# Expecting text output not numbers

Tags: c++

I have created a program that allows the user to input data into a week and they are allowed to choose the number of tasks which day do they want to insert the data.

User is able to view their input in days or it will display in a week.

I have tried this :

```
cout << sunday_task << '  ' << sunday_time << '  ' << monday_task << '  ' << 
monday_time << '  ' << tuesday_task << '  ' << tuesday_time << '  ' << 
wednesday_task << '  ' << wednesday_time << '  ' << thursday_task << '  ' << 
thursday_time << '  ' << friday_task << '  ' << friday_time << '  ' << 
saturday_task << '  ' << saturday_time << endl;
```

which gives me error for  multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]

```
 if (calendar_days == "Sunday" || calendar_days == "sunday") {
cout << "Task:  Time: " << endl;
work.print_task_sunday();
    to_restart();
    inside_days();
}
   else if (calendar_days == "Monday" || calendar_days == "monday") {
cout << "Task:  Time: " << endl;
work.print_task_monday();
    to_restart();
    inside_days();
  }
   else if (calendar_days == "Tuesday" || calendar_days =="tuesday"){
cout << "Task:  Time: " << endl;
work.print_task_tuesday();
    to_restart();
    inside_days();
      }
  else if (calendar_days == "Wednesday" || calendar_days == "wednesday") {
cout << "Task:  Time: " << endl;
work.print_task_wednesday();
    to_restart();
    inside_days();
   }
  else if (calendar_days == "Thursday" || calendar_days == "thursday") {
cout << "Task:  Time: " << endl;
work.print_task_thursday();
    to_restart();
    inside_days();
       }
 else if (calendar_days == "Friday" || calendar_days == "friday") {
cout << "Task:  Time: " << endl;
work.print_task_friday();
    to_restart();
    inside_days();
       }
 else if (calendar_days == "Saturday" || calendar_days == "saturday") {
cout << "Task:  Time: " << endl;
work.print_task_saturday();
    to_restart();
    inside_days();
   }
else if (calendar_days == "entire week" || calendar_days == "Entire week" || 
calendar_days == "Entire Week") {
string sunday_task;
int sunday_time;

string monday_task;
int monday_time;

string tuesday_task;
int tuesday_time;

string wednesday_task;
int wednesday_time;

string thursday_task;
int thursday_time;

string friday_task;
int friday_time;

string saturday_task;
int saturday_time;

ifstream file1("sunday_task.txt", ios::in);
ifstream file2("monday_task.txt", ios::in);
ifstream file3("tuesday_task.txt", ios::in);
ifstream file4("wednesday_task.txt", ios::in);
ifstream file5("thursday_task.txt", ios::in);
ifstream file6("friday_task.txt", ios::in);
ifstream file7("saturday_task.txt", ios::in);

ofstream ofile("all_task.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
ofile << file1.rdbuf() << file2.rdbuf() << file3.rdbuf() << 
file4.rdbuf() << file5.rdbuf() << file6.rdbuf() << file7.rdbuf();
cout << sunday_task << '  ' << sunday_time << '  ' << monday_task << '  ' << 
monday_time << '  ' << tuesday_task << '  ' << tuesday_time << '  ' << 
wednesday_task << '  ' << wednesday_time << '  ' << thursday_task << '  ' << 
thursday_time << '  ' << friday_task << '  ' << friday_time << '  ' << 
saturday_task << '  ' << saturday_time << endl;
```

The expected result is to print out

```
sundaytask1 930 mondaytask1 930 tuesdaytask1 930 wednesdaytask1 930 thursdaytask1 930 fridaytask1 930 saturdaytask1 930
```

but instead of that, it gives me random numbers.

This was the output it gives me
1878014496  10  4239492  1878014016  1877936777  6422120  3313664

Function

```
void to_restart() {
   cout << "Would you like to quit or to view calendar?" << endl;
   cout << "Answer quit or calendar? : " ;
   cin >> answer;
   getline(cin,temp);
   inside_days();
   }

  void inside_days() {
       if (answer == "calendar") {
       insert_calendar_days();



      }
 else if (answer == "quit") {
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
  else {
   cout << "Please enter calendar or quit" << endl;
     }
```

}

```
void insert_task_sunday() {
string sunday_task;
int sunday_time;
ofstream insert_task_sunday("sunday_task.txt");
int sunday_size;
cout << "Enter the number of task to be enter into sunday: ";
cin >> sunday_size;


for (int i = 0; i < sunday_size; i++) {
    cout << "Enter the task on sunday :" << endl;
    cin >> sunday_task;
    cout << "Time? ";
    cin >> sunday_time;

    insert_task_sunday << sunday_task << ' ' << sunday_time << endl;

}

insert_task_sunday.close();


}
```

void print_task_sunday() {

```
ifstream insert_task_sunday;
insert_task_sunday.open("sunday_task.txt");


while (true) {
    string sunday_task;
    int sunday_time;
    insert_task_sunday >> sunday_task >> sunday_time;
    if (insert_task_sunday.eof())break ;
    cout.width(6); cout << left << sunday_task << ' ' << sunday_time << endl;

}
insert_task_sunday.close();
```

}

Comment: Where are you assigning something to those variables?

Comment: @zereges sunday_task == sundaytask 1 and sunday_time == 930 and so on

Comment: @DuxtonLim That's not in your code. Even if it were, that's not assignment.

Comment: @DuxtonLim what problem are you still having?  As @melpomene indicated, you haven't assigned `sunday_task` a value.  After fixing two-space-character-constnats, the rest is working as written.  If you had posted full working code we could reproduce your error, but you haven't.  I copied your code and ran it and it works fine.

Comment: @Wyck I'm still having a problem trying to  output the expected output as shown above. sunday_task is not assign to a value but user will enter the value and store to the variable name sunday_task

Comment: We can't go any further until you show how you assign `sunday_task` a value.  Because if it has the right value, it will output the right content see my answer.  As it stands, it should be an empty string.  So if you are getting random numbers, you are running code you haven't shared with us.

Comment: @Wyck I have updated the post is that what u ask for?

Comment: Please provide a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/). @DuxtonLim This code isn't runnable, so we are not seeing all that you're doing. The bug may be in somewhere else too.

Comment: I have put the function that was connected to this problem @VermillionAzure but there wasn't any problem before I added the last else if which is equal to entire week

Comment: This is turning into a mess.   What is some example text that you are expecting to place into `sunday_task` by doing `cin >> sunday_task`?  Because using `>>`  with `cin` to a `string` will stop at the first space or new line.  For example it will **not** scan `sundaytask 1`.  It will just take `sundaytask`.   What are those numbers?  where did they come from?  Do you recognize them?

Comment: example I would put sundaytask1 into sunday_task and 930 to sunday_time... All works fine with me just when I try to combined them into a file and print it out it wouldnt work

Answer (score 0):

## Regarding the random numbers...

Those aren't random numbers, those are the values of your character constants with two spaces in them.

You are outputting a character literal with two spaces in it `'  '` instead of either a character literal with 1 space `' '` or a string with two spaces `"  "`.

Multiple characters in a character constant is implementation-defined behaviour.

> *The value of an integer character constant containing more than one
>   character or containing a character or escape sequence that does not
>   map to a single-byte execution character (C90 6.1.3.4, C99 and C11
>   6.4.4.4).* [See Implementation-defined behavior](http://www.rowleydownload.co.uk/arm/documentation/gnu/cpp/Implementation_002ddefined-behavior.html#Implementation_002ddefined-behavior).

Full repro:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << '  ';
}
```

Output (Visual Studio):

```
8224
```

## As for the rest of your problem...

This code (below) works for me.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string sunday_task = "sundaytask1";
    int sunday_time = 930;

    string monday_task = "mondaytask1";
    int monday_time = 930;

    string tuesday_task = "tuesdaytask1";
    int tuesday_time = 930;

    string wednesday_task = "wednesdaytask1";
    int wednesday_time = 930;

    string thursday_task = "thursdaytask1";
    int thursday_time = 930;

    string friday_task = "fridaytask1";
    int friday_time = 930;

    string saturday_task = "saturdaytask1";
    int saturday_time = 930;

    ifstream file1("sunday_task.txt", ios::in);
    ifstream file2("monday_task.txt", ios::in);
    ifstream file3("tuesday_task.txt", ios::in);
    ifstream file4("wednesday_task.txt", ios::in);
    ifstream file5("thursday_task.txt", ios::in);
    ifstream file6("friday_task.txt", ios::in);
    ifstream file7("saturday_task.txt", ios::in);

    ofstream ofile("all_task.txt", ios::out | ios::app);

    ofile << file1.rdbuf() << file2.rdbuf() << file3.rdbuf() <<
        file4.rdbuf() << file5.rdbuf() << file6.rdbuf() << file7.rdbuf();

    cout << sunday_task << ' ' << sunday_time << ' ' << monday_task << ' ' <<
        monday_time << ' ' << tuesday_task << ' ' << tuesday_time << ' ' <<
        wednesday_task << ' ' << wednesday_time << ' ' << thursday_task << ' ' <<
        thursday_time << ' ' << friday_task << ' ' << friday_time << ' ' <<
        saturday_task << ' ' << saturday_time << endl;
}
```

Comment: It still does not fix my problem but it did got rid of the error

Comment: @DuxtonLim what problem do you still need fixed?  Maybe you need to clarify your question.  I thought the random numbers were the problem.  The rest is working correctly, isn't it?  It works for me.  I've posted a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Although it depends on the input files and produces an output file.

Comment: Sorry my bad I will edit the question, it works fine but the output wasnt the output I was expected it still gives me random number not the output I was expecting